# What is the correct way of writing a binding for D3.js animations?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

I wonder how to create a d3js binding to simplify animations. I trying to use something similar to a dynamic version of TikZ coordinates, where you simply define a 2d coordinate and refer to it for positioning elements. Here I simply want to define an object M that encapsulate one value and some bindings to objects-attributes, e.g., radius of circle, x-position, y-position, ... . Every change of the value of M should animate the objects-attributes of attached objects at the *same* time.

I created a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/66qxjze9/1/

In this example:

```
test.addBinding(line,["x1","x2"],[]);
test.addBinding(dot,["cx1"],[]);
test.addBinding(dot2,["cy1"],[function(v){return 2*v;}]);
```

I wanted to animate the `x1, x2` attribute of a `line`, the `cx1` attribute of a `dot` and the `cy1` of `dot2` when I call `test.setValue(30);`.

Basically I thought it should work like

```
// on value changes
this.setValue = function(x){  
    // update the value itself
    this.v = x;
    // update each binded-object
    for(var i=0;i<this.entry.length;i++){
        var bindObject = this.entry[i];
        // update each binded-attribute of this object
        for(var j=0;j<bindObject.property.length;j++){

            // how to update? 
            // identify
            var modifier = function(x){return x;};
            // or a custom function ?
            if(typeof bindObject.function[j] !== "undefined"){
                modifier = bindObject.function[j];
            }

            var to = modifier(x);
            var attrName = bindObject.property[j];

            // update
            bindObject.handle
              .transition()
              .duration(2000)
              .attr(attrName, to);

        }

    }
};
```

My main idea is to use a wrapper for this value which knows which svg-attributes have to be changed.

I would like to use

```
// bind some svg elements
var test = new d3jsbinding();
test.addBinding(line,["x1","x2"],[]);
test.addBinding(dot,["cx1"],[]);
test.addBinding(dot2,["cx1"],[function(v){return 2*v;}]);

// update them (at the same time)
test.setValue(30);
```

Unfortunately I found no way to enqueue the attributes-updates (or better assign the new values of each attribute) before calling `.transition().duration(2000)`

Comment: This looks like a case of enter-update-delete using d3. If I get it correctly, you wish to update a given element based on the binding you add?

Comment: But the update should be animated in a linear transition. "enter-update-delete" would simply push it on the new position without animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at my [bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/PatWie/a68eed8e5773155c2571)

Essentially, you need to write the loop into:

```
d3.transition()
            .duration(parent.duration)
            .ease(parent.ease)
            .each(function() {
... HERE ...
});
```

disclaimer: